# Can I speed up the YUI layout manager, when I have a large table on the page?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, layout, yui

I am using the YUI layout manager which seems to work at an OK speed. However if the page contains a large `<Table>` with about 500 rows, the YUI `render()` function takes about a **minute** longer to run.

When I open the same page without the layout manager it opens in less than a second.

My *only* concern is with **IE 7**. I tried it on firefox and it only took about three seconds.

Any ideas on what is taking so long? Can I somehow tell the layout manager to ignore the table?

Comment: Is this topic too specialized for stackoverflow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured it out myself.

The trick is to hide the content that should be ignored by the layout manager.

Before calling `render()` set the `style.display = 'none'` for a tag that contains a large chunk of the page you don't need the layout manager to manage. Set it back to normal after with `style.display = 'block'`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the render() method of your large table is taking a long time?

the YUI DataTable has a [renderLoopSize](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/#renderLoop) property specifically for this kind of situation. It makes the table render to the DOM every X rows, rather than waiting till the end and rendering them all in 1 go.

```
var myDataTable = new YAHOO.widget.DataTable("myContainer", 
                         myColumnDefs, 
                         myDataSource, 
                        {renderLoopSize: 100});
```